# Galois image of CM elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve with CM, with the endomorphism ring $R=\mathrm{End}_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}(E)$. Then for any integer $m$, we have the mod-$m$ Galois representation $\rho_m:\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}) \hookrightarrow (R/mR)^{*}$. I would like to understand the image. Page 12 in a [master thesis](https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/master/algant/2017-2018/campagna-master-thesis.pdf) says the image has a bounded index (in $(R/mR)^{*}$) when $m$ is large enough, but I couldn't find any other reference for this. If it is true, can anyone provide a suitable reference?